# Add existing AppSync API to AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-codebuild

#### The problem

When I run CodeBuild inside of Amplify, my AppSync credentials are overwritten, breaking the build.

#### Details

I'm building a ReactJS site using AWS Amplify as the backend. The project is being deployed using the Amplify built-in CodeBuild. The AppSync API was created separately to Amplify, and doesn't directly appear in the Amplify console.

When I run `amplify codegen add --apiId xxx`, the `aws-exports.js` file is generated, with the following fields:

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-west-2",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://xxxxx.appsync-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "eu-west-2",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "xxxxx"
};
```

However, when the Amplify Frontend CodeBuild job runs, the AppSync fields are not present. Running `amplifyPush --simple` during the Backend job overwrites the `aws-exports.js` file with the following:

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-west-2"
};
```

This is the same format which the `amplifyPush --simple` command seems to be generating. The result of this is during the build, React cannot find the variables it needs.

```
> react-scripts build
  [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
  [INFO]: Failed to compile.
  [INFO]: /codebuild/output/src143434459/src/site/src/index.tsx
          TypeScript error in
          /codebuild/output/src143434459/src/site/src/index.tsx(12,20):
          
          Property 'aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint' does not exist on type 
          '{ aws_project_region: string; }'.  TS2339

          10 |
          11 | export const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
        > 12 |     url: awsconfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
             |                    ^
          13 |     region: awsconfig.aws_appsync_region,
          14 |     auth: {
          15 |         type: AUTH_TYPE.API_KEY,
```

#### My aim

I want the `aws_appsync` variables within the `aws-exports.js` file to be present after being generated by CodeBuild. I don't want to keep the API key in version control, so having it provisioned during the build process is ideal.

#### What I've tried already

- Looking into if it's possible to run the `amplify codegen add --apiId xxx` job during the front-end build, but since it takes parameters I'm not sure how do achieve this.
- Looking into trying to add the API to Amplify itself, since I created it separately to Amplify. Then `amplify env pull` would get these environment details correctly.

[Screenshot showing empty API tab in Amplify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35nbN.png)

---

#### Files involved

##### amplify.yml

This is the default file which comes with a new ReactJS / Amplify project.

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

##### index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import AWSAppSyncClient, { AUTH_TYPE } from 'aws-appsync';
import awsconfig from 'aws-exports';


export const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: awsconfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
    region: awsconfig.aws_appsync_region,
    auth: {
        type: AUTH_TYPE.API_KEY,
        apiKey: awsconfig.aws_appsync_apiKey,
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Hey Struan. I was facing the same issue. Since some time went by: did you find any solution you are able to share? Cheers

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply @mak, I never figured it out, and ended up abandoning GraphQL and moving over to a REST API.